# BootStrap CSS Seattle master page

Tags: custom-masterpage, boot-strap

I have copied the seattle masterpage called it BootstrapMaster. The masterpage works fine. I have downloaded twitter bootstrap and placed it in the location _catalogs/masterpage/CSS/bootstrap.min.css

I have added them to the head section of the masterpage

```
    <link href="https://test11.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://test11.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/1033/styles/searchv15.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
```

However when is this right and whats the best way to test whether the style is getting applied?

I don't this is getting picked up when I check in chrome tools.

Comment: did you then set this as the site masterpage, is it giving you a 404 error when loading the css file?

Comment: I agree with Eric, check if the masterpage is applied and it is approved in the Masterpage and Page Layouts gallery, also try this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/bootstrap.min.css"></style>
 by uploading the css to the style library